# Problem adding user profiles on asus zenpad z380 lollipop 5.0.2

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, multi-user

I just bought an Asus Zenpad Z380, running on lollipop 5.0.2. I wanted to add another user/profile- but can't find the function anywhere. From what I read after I googled the question- one should be simply able to swipe down and there should be users and below that- a + sign to add more, only except that there isn't (for me, at least). I get only the one(main) user profile. tapping on it leads me to the profile itself on the contact list, and that's it!

My husband ran the setting up process (It's supposed to be a joint tablet). Could it be that he "took a wrong turn"- A.K.A missed something during the process, or is this a known (and hopefully fixable) problem?

Comment: What you read referred to a "pure" Android interface. Asus' ZenUI interface is very far from "pure" Android as it is heavily OEM-customized, and as such most of the instructions you find online is N/A for you, as they will refer to the "common", "pure" Android interface.